# Sensor de temeperatura dht 22 deja de funcionar

Tags: arduino

Tengo una palca `Arduino Uno` con una placa `Ethernet Shield`, le tengo conectado un sensor de temperatura `DHT22`, un módulo `ADS1115`, un sensor de consumo `SCT013`, y dos sensores magnéticos de contacto (como los de las alarmas caseras).

Tengo todo mi código funcionando ok, enviando datos a mi hosting sin problemas, sucede que estoy tomando lecturas de temperatura cada 2 segundos, y allí mismo leo el consumo del `SCT013`.

Cuando el "electrodoméstico" al cual le tengo conectado el `SCT013` está apagado, el `DHT` lee normal la temperatura, pero, en cuanto prendo el electrodoméstico y el `SCT` empieza a leer el consumo, el `DHT` deja de leer, dándome éste dato en el monitor (`nan&`) o al contrario, enciendo el electrodoméstico y el `SCT` como el `DHT` leen normal pero si apago el electrodoméstico el `DHT` deja de leer.

Tengo la placa arduino alimentada con un cargador de 9V a 1A.

La verdad no logro identificar cual es el problema, he armado mi proyecto leyendo en un foro y otro he implementando código según iba avanzando, tal vez no es el mejor código pero me ha funcionado:

```js
#include "DHT.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_ADS1015.h>
#include <Adafruit_MLX90614.h>
#include <UniversalTelegramBot.h>

#define DHTPIN1 2
#define DHTPIN2 3
#define DHTTYPE DHT22
DHT dht1(DHTPIN1,DHTTYPE); // inicializar sensor de temperatura 1
DHT dht2(DHTPIN2,DHTTYPE); // inicializar sensor de temperatura 2

#define BOT_TOKEN "mi_token"
#define CHAT_ID "mi_id"


// Instanciar objeto ADS
Adafruit_ADS1115 ads(0x48);

//definir variables de conversion de consumo  
const float FACTOR = 50; //30A/1V
const float multiplier = 0.0495F;

int entradapuerta1 = 8; // entrada de puerta 1
int entradapuerta2 = 9; // entrada de puerta 2
int entradapuerta3 = 4; // entrada de puerta 1
int entradapuerta4 = 5; // entrada de puerta 2


float humidityData1;
float temperatureData1;
float humidityData2;
float temperatureData2;
float consumo;
int punto;
int cuarto;
int puerta1;
int puerta2;
int valorpuerta1 = 0; //puerta de cuanto frio 1
int valorpuerta2 = 0; //puerta de cuanto frio 2
int valorpuerta3 = 0; //puerta de cuanto frio 3
int valorpuerta4 = 0; //puerta de cuanto frio 4
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
char server[] = "www.miserver.com.co";    // name address for Google (using DNS)

IPAddress ip(192, 110, 40, 145);
IPAddress myDns(192, 110, 40, 105);

EthernetClient client;

// Variables to measure the speed
unsigned long beginMicros, endMicros;
unsigned long byteCount = 0;
bool printWebData = true;  // set to false for better speed measurement

void ImprimirMedidas(String prefix, float value, String postfix);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht1.begin();
  dht2.begin();
  pinMode(entradapuerta1, INPUT); //seteamos la puerta 1 como entrada
  pinMode(entradapuerta2, INPUT); //seteamos la puerta 2 como entrada
  pinMode(entradapuerta3, INPUT); //seteamos la puerta 3 como entrada
  pinMode(entradapuerta4, INPUT); //seteamos la puerta 4 como entrada
  ads.setGain(GAIN_TWO);        // ±2.048V  1 bit = 0.0625mV
  ads.begin();
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  // start the Ethernet connection:
  Serial.println("Initialize Ethernet with DHCP:");
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // Check for Ethernet hardware present
    if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
      Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found.  Sorry, can't run without hardware. :(");
      while (true) {
        delay(1); // do nothing, no point running without Ethernet hardware
      }
    }
    if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
      Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
    }
    // try to configure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, myDns);
  } else {
    Serial.print("  DHCP assigned IP ");
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  }
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.print(server);
  Serial.println("...");
}

void loop() {
  float CorrienteRMS1 = getCorriente1();
  float Potencia = 120.0 * CorrienteRMS1;
 
  ImprimirMedidas("Irms: ", CorrienteRMS1, "A ,");
  ImprimirMedidas("Potencia: ", Potencia, "W");

  float CorrienteRMS2 = getCorriente2();
  float Potencia2 = 120.0 * CorrienteRMS2;
 
  ImprimirMedidas("Irms: ", CorrienteRMS2, "A ,");
  ImprimirMedidas("Potencia: ", Potencia2, "W");
  
  valorpuerta1 = digitalRead(entradapuerta1);
  valorpuerta2 = digitalRead(entradapuerta2);
  valorpuerta3 = digitalRead(entradapuerta3);
  valorpuerta4 = digitalRead(entradapuerta4);
  if (valorpuerta1 == HIGH && valorpuerta2 == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("cerrada completamente");
    puerta1 = 1;//Serial.println(entrada);
  }
  if(valorpuerta1 == LOW && valorpuerta2 == HIGH){
    Serial.println("cerrada a medias");
    puerta1 = 2;//Serial.println(entrada);
  }
  if(valorpuerta1 == HIGH && valorpuerta2 == LOW){
    Serial.println("cerrada a medias");
    puerta1 = 2;//Serial.println(entrada);
  }
  if (valorpuerta1 == LOW && valorpuerta2 == LOW) {
    Serial.println("ABIERTA");
    puerta1 = 3;//Serial.println(entrada);
  }
  if (valorpuerta3 == HIGH && valorpuerta4 == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("cerrada completamente");
    puerta2 = 1;//Serial.println(entrada);
  }
  if(valorpuerta3 == LOW && valorpuerta4 == HIGH){
    Serial.println("cerrada a medias");
    puerta2 = 2;//Serial.println(entrada);
  }
  if(valorpuerta3 == HIGH && valorpuerta4 == LOW){
    Serial.println("cerrada a medias");
    puerta2 = 2;//Serial.println(entrada);
  }
  if (valorpuerta3 == LOW && valorpuerta4 == LOW) {
    Serial.println("ABIERTA");
    puerta2 = 3;//Serial.println(entrada);
  }
  
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {//REGISTROS CUARTO FRIO 1 CONGELACION
    humidityData1 = dht1.readHumidity();
    temperatureData1 = dht1.readTemperature();
    consumo= CorrienteRMS1;
    punto=1;
    cuarto=1;
    Serial.print("connected to ");
    Serial.println(client.remoteIP());
    // Make a HTTP request:
    Serial.print("GET /sensores/anadir.php?humidity=");
    client.print("GET /sensores/anadir.php?humidity="); 
    Serial.print(humidityData1);
    client.print(humidityData1);
    client.print("&temperature=");
    Serial.print("&temperature=");
    client.print(temperatureData1);
    Serial.print(temperatureData1);
    client.print("&consumo=");
    Serial.print("&consumo=");
    client.print(consumo);
    Serial.print(consumo);
    client.print("&puerta=");
    Serial.print("&puerta=");
    client.print(puerta1);
    Serial.print(puerta1);
    client.print("&cuarto=");
    Serial.print("&cuarto=");
    client.print(cuarto);
    Serial.print(cuarto);
    client.print("&punto=");
    Serial.print("&punto=");
    client.print(punto);
    Serial.print(punto);
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: www.mi_host.com.co");
    //client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();

    //REGISTROS DE CUARTO FRIO 2 REFRIGERACION
    humidityData2 = dht2.readHumidity();
    temperatureData2 = dht2.readTemperature();
    consumo= CorrienteRMS2;
    //consumo= 9;
    punto=1;
    cuarto=2;
    Serial.print("connected to ");
    Serial.println(client.remoteIP());
    // Make a HTTP request:
    Serial.print("GET /sensores/anadir.php?humidity=");
    client.print("GET /sensores/anadir.php?humidity="); 
    Serial.print(humidityData2);
    client.print(humidityData2);
    client.print("&temperature=");
    Serial.print("&temperature=");
    client.print(temperatureData2);
    Serial.print(temperatureData2);
    client.print("&consumo=");
    Serial.print("&consumo=");
    client.print(consumo);
    Serial.print(consumo);
    client.print("&puerta=");
    Serial.print("&puerta=");
    client.print(puerta2);
    Serial.print(puerta2);
    client.print("&cuarto=");
    Serial.print("&cuarto=");
    client.print(cuarto);
    Serial.print(cuarto);
    client.print("&punto=");
    Serial.print("&punto=");
    client.print(punto);
    Serial.print(punto);
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: www.mi_host.com.co");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();

  } else {
    // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
  beginMicros = micros();

  int len = client.available();
  if (len > 0) {
    byte buffer[80];
    if (len > 80) len = 80;
    client.read(buffer, len);
    if (printWebData) {
      Serial.write(buffer, len); // show in the serial monitor (slows some boards)
    }
    byteCount = byteCount + len;
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Conexión perdida.");
    if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkON) {   // Si el cable Ethernet está conectado
      Serial.println("Intentando reconectar...");
      client.connect(server, 80);            // Intentar reconectar al servidor
      delay(1000);
    }
      
  }
delay(1000); // tiempo entre cada nueva lectura cada 2 minutos
}
void ImprimirMedidas(String prefix, float value, String postfix)
{
 Serial.print(prefix);
 Serial.print(value, 3);
 Serial.println(postfix);
}
 
float getCorriente1()
{
  float Volt_diferencial1;
  float corriente;
  float sum = 0;
  long tiempo = millis();
  int counter = 0;
 
  while (millis() - tiempo < 1000)
  {
    Volt_diferencial1 = ads.readADC_Differential_0_1() * multiplier;
   
   //-----------------------------------------------------
   //Volt_diferencial = ads.readADC_Differential_2_3() * multiplier;
   //-----------------------------------------------------
   
   corriente = Volt_diferencial1 * FACTOR;
   corriente /= 1000.0;
 
   sum += sq(corriente);
   counter = counter + 1;
  }
  corriente = sqrt(sum / counter);
  return(corriente);
}

float getCorriente2()
{
  float Volt_diferencial2;
  float corriente;
  float sum = 0;
  long tiempo = millis();
  int counter = 0;
 
  while (millis() - tiempo < 1000)
  {
    //Volt_diferencial = ads.readADC_Differential_0_1() * multiplier;
   
   //-----------------------------------------------------
   Volt_diferencial2 = ads.readADC_Differential_2_3() * multiplier;
   //-----------------------------------------------------
   
   corriente = Volt_diferencial2 * FACTOR;
   corriente /= 1000.0;
 
   sum += sq(corriente);
   counter = counter + 1;
  }
  corriente = sqrt(sum / counter);
  return(corriente);
}
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda, he logrado hacerlo funcionar gracias a varios hilos de este foro.

---

asi tengo las conexiones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el cable que sostengo con la mano va coenctado al sct013, que esta a una gran distancia

Comment: Puede que sea debido a la inrush current que genera tu dispositivo al encenderlo? Has probado a colocar un condensador para mitigar este efecto? Si tu código funciona correctamente hasta que efectúas un paso de ON a OFF o viceversa, me temo que se debe a un ‘error’ hardware más que software.

Comment: Donde podria conectar el condensador?

Comment: Conectado a masa en la línea que conecta tu periférico. En este link tienes más información sobre cómo mitigar este efecto: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva670a/slva670a.pdf?ts=1681367517144&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: no lo capto aun, el sensor sct013 la conectado a un modulo ads1115, ademas el electrodomestico esta muy alejado de mi placa arduino.

Comment: Hm, no es evidente cómo tienes todo eso enchufado a la placa. Es posible que, en el momento que el sensor de consumo actúa, puede haber algo que hace que las lecturas del DHT fallen (mal cableado, corriente insuficiente). Puedes probar usando sólo el SCT y mide cómo se comportan corriente y voltaje; luego sólo el DHT... y así. Que se dé en esos eventos indica que va por ahí la cosa...

Comment: adjunte unas imagenes como respuesta pero me las bloquearon..

Comment: Si encontraste solución, ponla abajo en el campo Tu Respuesta, con detalle como hiciste con la pregunta. Es súper interesante! (PD. Las imagenes salían como revertidas por ti, reversé el cambio en la pregunta para que salieran)

Comment: ok, aun no me familiarizo con la metodologia de este foro.. por ahora la solucion de paso que he encontrado es validar si recibo lecturas "nan" y "reiniciar" el pin donde se conecta el sensor con un digitalWrite(DHTPIN2, LOW); y luego con un digitalWrite(DHTPIN2, HIGH);

Comment: Edito, sigue sin funcionar, despues de que empieza a leer datos "nan" ya no regresa a su estado normal, debo quitar la alimentacion a la placa arduino y volver a coenctarla, alli retoma nuevamente las lecturas normalmente.